# Injection order of "MembersInjector" and a regular "Method"-Injection wrong?

Tags: java, guice

I am using google-guice since a couple of days,  and I am getting more and more impressed.

I created a MemberInjector to easily integrate the logging framework SLF4J, just with a additional annotation.  That means instead of using always the long term:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

I am now just using:

```
@Log
Logger LOG;
```

This is really great, BUT:
I am also using a method-injection as a kind of starter function like this in the same class, AND if I access to the LOG instance there, it causes a NPE! Because it is not injected yet.

```
@Inject
public void start() { 
    //And here is the problem...
    LOG.info("in start")  //causes NPE, cause LOG is not injected yet
}
```

If I use the LOG instance in another (non-injected) method it works perfectly,.

Is there a way to change the injection order or is it possible to tell guice to inject the MemberInjector earlier? Cause I really would like to use the logging also in the method-injection part.

Thank for any hint.

Comment: Why do you use Inject on a paremeterless method? It should be placed on a constructor or a setter ...

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is because we are restructuring our application and wanted to get rid of this old huge spring implementation (declared everything in xml...) and there was this "init-method=..." and for the first shot we did not change the logic only the structure. So we were looking for a counterpart of "init-method=" in spring... and a parameterless method with Inject works exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to create just a additional listener that looks for a defined method like ("init" or "start") and just calls it after creation and injection of members.

See in module configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bindListener(Matchers.any(), new InitMethodTypeListener());
    //...
```

InitMethodTypeListener:

```
public class InitMethodTypeListener implements TypeListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitMethodTypeListener.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    static class InitInvoker implements InjectionListener {
        @Override
        public void afterInjection(final Object injectee) {
            try {
                log.info("Invoke init() from Class: {}", injectee.getClass().getName());
                injectee.getClass().getMethod("init").invoke(injectee);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        public static final InitInvoker INSTANCE = new InitInvoker();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <I> void hear(final TypeLiteral<I> type, final TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {

        try {
            if (type.getRawType().getMethod("init") != null) {
                encounter.register(InitInvoker.INSTANCE);
            }
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // do nothing here, if not init-method found - no call
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it not the straight forward way but it works. And so I am sure all members are injected well when the init-method is called.

With this implementation all objects that are under guice control their "init"-method will be called automatically after object creation and injection.